# Which one for Android Database?

Tags: android, mysql, database, sqlite

I need your help about Android Database. I have been designing a kind of meeting app.
 I am so confused about using MySql or SQLite or both. As I know, SqLite provides local DBase.   However, my app will be published and anyone can use it.
 My question is,
 for this app which one do I supposed to choose and which database management system is convenient for my app ?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: sqlite is the best one it provide optional in android device

Comment: Motorola have created a nice eclipse plugin to help creating contentproviders and manage database operations on Android: http://sourceforge.net/motorola/motodev/home/Home/

Comment: I think for Android SQLite is the best..

Comment: Do you wish to use a library which is built from mySql? With that you need not write any sql statements. Easy as 123.

Comment: You normally use MySQL in a remote server, SQLite internally in your application. I don't think you can even get MySQL in Android...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SQLite is great for testing and prototyping, or for embedding in applications. MySQL is worthy of (large scale) production environments.**

[When to use SQLite?](http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html)

For Android SQLite is the best option. You can create your database externally in SQLite and then you can utilize it by copying it into your application's assets folder and use it directly.

It's really a design decision, SQLite offers a very robust way to organize and persist your data, you're only other options are to write to a file, or to save in SharedPrefs, both methods become a lot harder to manage once the size of your data begins to grow, as you must manually keep a list of objects and manage their names etc etc.

**Pros:**

- If your application gets closed the in memory data will be lost, but after that you will be able to restore the state from the database if you have one
- Especially for the case of complex calculations it is good to store the result once in the database and not recalculate it multiple times on demand
- The database will untie your UI from the internet connection and thus you will be able to display results even if there is not internet connection
- Using database you will be able to fetch the updated data from a background service, without impacting your UI
- Organizing your data in database usually makes it a lot easier to manage all the application data.

**Cons:**

- Adding database will require a bit of additional effort on your side

Answer (score 0):

Hi As Per My Opinion You Have To Use Sqlite Database Becoz generally In Mobile Application Use The Sqlite Database because other Database take load in mobile applications.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite:

- easier to setup
- great for temporary (testing databases)
- great for rapid development
- great for embedding in an application
- doesn't have user management
- doesn't have many performance features
- doesn't scale well.

MySQL:

- far more difficult/complex to set up
- better options for performance tuning
- can scale well if tuned properly
- can manage users, permissions, etc.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630/sqlite-vs-mysql